# jQuery timed function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not to familiar with jQuery and have tried to set up a conditional statement for hiding a footer when a panel is slid out onto the page using jQuery.

I'm trying to detect whether the panel is out, if so hide the footer, and if the panel is in to show the footer. However I'm trying to avoid having the footer flash on and off as the user switches between panels.

Comment: Sorry what is the error?

Comment: You really have to show us your HTML and probably need to learn some basic javascript, but I suspect this: `if ((objSlidePanel).class('out')); {` should be this: `if ((objSlidePanel).hasClass('out')) {`.  Change to .`hasClass()` and remove the semicolon.

Comment: `//footer condition
if ((objSlidePanel).hasClass('out')); {
    $('#foot').delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
} else {
    $('#foot').delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
}
`

Comment: I cant figure out the correct syntax for the conditional statment, as i had help with other parts of the code, im not to sure how to build the conditional statement. :/

Comment: ok, yeah try .hasClass that should check for the class

Comment: Like i said im just bumbling through this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(settings.objSlideTrigger).bind('click' , function() {

    if ( $('.panel').hasClass('out') )
        slidePanelIn();

    settings.objSlidePanel = "#"+ $(this).data('content') +"";        

    //If the panel isn't out
    if(!$(settings.objSlidePanel).hasClass('out')) {
        slidePanelOut();
         $('#foot').delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
    } else if($(settings.objSlidePanel).hasClass('out')) {
        slidePanelIn();
         $('#foot').delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
   $(function(){ 
    if ((objSlidePanel).hasClass('out')) {

        $('#foot').delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
        }
        else{
        $('#foot').delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
        }


        });
```

Comment: Have to at least remove the semicolon on the 2nd line.  Also no point in putting $(function(){` around it because it looks like they already have `objSlidePanel`.

Comment: can u set up a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($('#objSlidePanel').hasClass('out')) {
    $('#foot').delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
}
else{
    $('#foot').delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Your syntax was wrong.